# Is Helioseismology on topic in Earth Science or Astronomy?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is says on the tin, is Helioseismology on topic in Earth Science or Astronomy?

Myself I'd think no (for ES) as although it takes elements of seismology, I think there is a fundamental difference in what's being looked at, perhaps in the same way that advanced studies of bells and bell ringing would also not be on topic.

but anyway, just something I was curious about what other people think.

Answer (score 7):

I too would say astronomy. Or maybe physics (under the guise of astrophysics). Let those two duke it out.